# How to send a form using javascript without being redirected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use to work with the `submit(callback)` jQuery method, in the callback i serialize my form and do an `ajax post` call.

But this time, i need to upload a file, and this method desn't seems to work, so i try to directly submit the form with the `submit()` jQuery method, but i am not able to avoid the redirection, i am however calling `e.preventDefault();` before:

```
$('form.input.upload').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('form.example').submit();
});
```

Comment: @apsillers serialize doesn't serialize file type inputs. He'll need to use a separate jQuery plugin for that, or submit the form to a hidden iframe (which won't be as nice, but it gets the job done pretty well for small uploads).

Comment: HTML form submission requires redirection. Your intuition to use Ajax is correct -- however, `.serialize` does not handle file data for `<input type="file">`, so you'll need to collect that yourself using a `FileReader`.

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) has a similar question, and several possible solutions. See if that suits your needs :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do `preventDefault` in the `onsubmit` event of the `<form>`, not in the `onchange` event of the `<input>`:

```
$("form.example").on("submit", function (e) {
  // preventing browser's native form submit
  e.preventDefault();
});

$("form.example input.upload").on("change", function (e) {
  // auto-submit if input.upload changed
  $("form.example").submit();
});
```

Update: Before my edit I wasn't exactly correct. The onsubmit event will be fired by clicking on an `<input type="submit">` or by pressing Enter in any focused `<input>`. But: the event is not triggered if you call the `submit()` function programmatically.

And well, thinking deeper, your real problem - the file uploading - is a bit harder than my answer. The by the comment linked question has a very good answer to this ;)